# trigger button to be clicked after option from drop down is selected

Tags: jquery, select, button, triggers, click

I have the following problem:

When an option from the dropdown list is selected it should be added to the searchbox. This works. But now I want the "GO" button to be clicked when automatically as soon as this has happenned. With the code I have so far, I'm trying to use the

```
  $('input[name="go"]').trigger("click");
```

part to achieve this. The problem however, is that this last event is triggered as soon as the dropdown box is clicked (and thus before an option can be selected). I tried many things, but I'm not very experienced with jquery.
(btw: I'm using a pre-existing search field and button)

This is the javascript/jquery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('select[name="Articlecategories"]').bind('click', function() {



     $('select[name="Articlecategories"]').change(function () { 
           var str = "";
           $('select[name="Articlecategories"] option:selected').each(function () {
                str += $(this).text() + " ";
                 });
            $('input[name="searchfield"]').val(str);
     })

    .change();

    $('input[name="searchfield"]').change(function () { 
    $('input[name="go"]').trigger("click");
     }) 
    .change();

    });


    });
```

And this the html:

```
  <select name="Artikelcategorien"  >
    <option selected="selected" disabled>select an option</option>
    <option >Candy</option>
    <option>Taffy</option>
    <option>Caramel</option>
    <option>Fudge</option>
    <option>Cookie</option>
  </select>

<input type="text" name="searchfield" value="" >
    <input type="submit" name="go" value="GO" >
```

Answer (score 1):

`.trigger()` only executes the function attached to certain element not executes default behaviours of that element.

You can use this if have all above in `form` element.

```
$("form").submit();
```

Comment: Unfortunatally it is not that easy I think. The drop-down list (select tag) is not part of a a form. The button is a submitbutton however, but it is originally meant to use in combination with the "searchfield". I would like to modify the code so that a user can select a word from the drop-down list, the word is placed in the searchfield, and the GO-button is then automatically triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the form via

```
$("formID").submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just submit the form (presuming that this lives within a form of course):

```
$('form#formId').submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, never mind, I maneged to solve it. Not the most elegant solution perhaps, but it works:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $('select[name="Articlecategories"]').change(Klikzoeken)


    });

    function Klikzoeken() {

     $('select[name="Articlecategories"]')
           var str = "";
           $('select[name="Articlecategories"] option:selected').each(function () {
                str += $(this).text();
                 });
            $('input[name="searchfield"]').val(str);

    $('input[name="go"]').click();


    }
```